# How to apply css for only 2nd div element from 1st when image code is between them using combinator or any other way?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I have 4 div. 1st header which is fixed position and other 3 are simple div.
For applying margin-top:2%; CSS for only div section 1. I use the General Sibling Selector (~). 
By using this header section to div then it applies to all div i.e section 1,2 and 3 also. 
Because of 1 image code is between the header and other div section, Adjacent Sibling Selector (+) also not working.

I want to apply margin-top to only on div Section 1.

**Note:** Actually Problem is that I am working on a project which is 80% done (Almost 290 pages). So going on every page & mention a class for Section 1's div and apply margin-top CSS is time-consuming.
Thatswhy I want a tricky solution.

External CSS is used in the project which is mentioned in the following code which I tried in my project.

```css
.header {
  z-index: 200;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70x;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #fbfcfe;
}

.header ~ div {
  margin-top: 2%;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.sec {
  height: 250px;
  padding-top: 7%;
}

.backtotop {
  width: 61px;
  height: 61px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 99;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-12 header">
<p> Header Section </p>
</div>

<img src="image.png" class="backtotop"  width="50px" height="50px">

<div class="col-md-12 sec">
<p> Section 1 </p>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12 sec">
<p> Section 2 </p>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12 sec">
<p> Section 3 </p>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried :first-child ?

Comment: This HTML structure looks wrong for Bootstrap 3. Where are the `.container` and `.row` elements?

Comment: @Paulie_D , I just specify the code where the problem exists. I want to apply CSS code for section 1's div. Combinators are working only if image code is not in between the header and section 1. Thatswhy I added here only 4 div except container and row.

Comment: @Vikas Jadhav , There are no parent element, 4 divs are separate with each other so I first-child will not work there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sure that `img` tag comes to every page, you can use the following 'hacky' CSS to give `margin-top`

```
.header ~ img.backtotop + div {
    margin-top: 2%;
}
```

```css
.header {
  z-index: 200;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70x;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #fbfcfe;
}

.header~img.backtotop+div {
  margin-top: 2%;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.sec {
  height: 250px;
  padding-top: 7%;
}

.backtotop {
  width: 61px;
  height: 61px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 99;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-12 header">
  <p> Header Section </p>
</div>

<img src="image.png" class="backtotop" width="50px" height="50px">

<div class="col-md-12 sec">
  <p> Section 1 </p>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12 sec">
  <p> Section 2 </p>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12 sec">
  <p> Section 3 </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Allan Jebaraj, Great Trick, Nice 'hacky' CSS. Thank you so much for your help. It is so useful for me.  :)